# Join multiple tables in sybase

Tags: sql, sybase

i need help joining the below 2 selects on a sybase database.

```
SELECT HOST_ENTRY.ID
      ,HOST.NAME
      ,HOST_ENTRY.TYPE
      ,HOST_ENTRY.NAME
      ,HOST_ENTRY.IP
      ,HOST_ENTRY.IP_LAST
      ,HOST_ENTRY.NETADDR
      ,HOST_ENTRY.MASK  
from HOST_ENTRY
INNER JOIN HOST
ON HOST_ENTRY.HOST_ID=HOST.ID;

SELECT  HOST_GRP_MEMBER.ID
       ,HOST_GROUP.NAME
       ,HOST.NAME
from HOST_GRP_MEMBER 
INNER JOIN HOST_GROUP ON HOST_GRP_MEMBER.GROUP_ID=HOST_GROUP.ID 
INNER JOIN HOST ON HOST_GRP_MEMBER.HOST_ID=HOST.ID 
ORDER BY HOST_GROUP.NAME
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I only saw your sql But I don't know their relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about -

```
SELECT HOST_ENTRY.ID
      ,HOST.NAME
      ,HOST_ENTRY.TYPE
      ,HOST_ENTRY.NAME
      ,HOST_ENTRY.IP
      ,HOST_ENTRY.IP_LAST
      ,HOST_ENTRY.NETADDR
      ,HOST_ENTRY.MASK  
      ,HOST_GRP_MEMBER.ID
      ,HOST_GROUP.NAME
      ,HOST.NAME
from HOST_ENTRY
INNER JOIN HOST ON HOST_ENTRY.HOST_ID=HOST.ID;
INNER JOIN HOST_GRP_MEMBER ON HOST_GRP_MEMBER.HOST_ID=HOST.ID
INNER JOIN HOST_GROUP ON HOST_GRP_MEMBER.GROUP_ID=HOST_GROUP.ID 
ORDER BY HOST_GROUP.NAME
```